# How to add SharePoint list data or Google sheet to Active Campaign lists?

Tags: google-sheets, integration, sharepoint-online, power-automate, activecampaign

I am using SharePoint Online lists as a backend. I have requirements like when users add data to the SharePoint list, the same data needs to be added to the Active Campaign lists. There is no direct connector for Active Campaign under Power Automate. So, I have tried with HTTPClient with Angular but it does not allow GET/POST calls from the browser. It threw me a CORS error. Is there any alternative to making an Active Campaign API call from the client side using HTTPClient?

For a workaround, I have created a flow using Power Automate. There is a direct connector for Google Sheets under Power Automat. So, when the user adds new data to the SharePoint list, the same data will be added to the Google Sheets with Power Automate.

Now, I have imported that Google sheets data to Active Campaign lists. For that, I have used ActiveCampaign Google Sheets integration. But it is not working correctly. I am unable to import Google Sheets data to Active Campaign lists.

Below is the reference link for the same,

https://help.activecampaign.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001388224-how-to-send-contact-information-to-a-google-sheet#use-the-activecampaign-google-sheets-integration-0-0

Can anyone help me with the same?

Thanks